# C# and ACCESS SQL (*.accdb)

Tags: c#, ms-access

OK people I write my first C# program with DB and I have a problem. I take from ACCESS db, direction where is file I need to copy ("String my_query"). In Access query is working but my program can't take this string and copy file from it... What am I doing wrong ? p.s. Sorry for my English

This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mysheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myrange;
    excel.Workbooks.Open("E:\\access\\Book1.xlsm");
    //excel.Visible = true;
    mysheet = excel.Worksheets[1];
    myrange = mysheet.Cells;
    int lastrow = mysheet.UsedRange.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= lastrow; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myrange.Item[i, 1].Value);
        string fileName = myrange.Item[i, 1].Value + ".pdf";
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data source= E:\ACCESS\test.accdb";
        conn.Open();
        String my_query = "SELECT adres FROM zrodla WHERE RIGHT(adres,21) = '" + fileName + "'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //DateTime ddd = DateTime.Now;
        //string ddd2 = ddd.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //string miesiac = ddd.ToString("MM");
        //string dzien = ddd.ToString("dd");
        string sourcePath = cmd.ToString();
        string targetPath = @"E:\ACCESS\ho\";
   
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sourcePath+fileName))
        {
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Plik nie istnieje!: " + fileName+"\n");
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            conn2.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data source= E:\ACCESS\test.accdb";
            conn2.Open();
            String my_query2 = "INSERT INTO dane(appid) VALUES('"+fileName+"')" ;
            OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(my_query, conn2);
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in "string sourcePath"  i need result of query like "E:\pb\send\2017-05-03\A_20160202000555555.pdf" but results is 0... i don't have any ideas why in sourcePath always is 0 - not direction saved in access record..

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteNonQuery will not return any results, while I suspect you want to get the results of the query, which you can't do just by using cmd.ToString.

The right way is to use ExecuteReader, which returns a data reader you can use to examine the results. The reader looks at one row at a time, and you can examine the contents of various columns, and you can move to the next row. I'm sure there are plenty of resources out there to help you work with the reader, such as https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx

Comment: i try with ExecuteReader but still error... maybe problem is result of the query? "E:\pb\send\2017-05-03\A_20160202000555555.pdf"

Comment: The error message might be helpful in determining where the problem is. Otherwise we'd just be guessing blindly.